# Creating threaded messages with Gmail API

Tags: gmail-api

I am using the Gmail "insert" API to create messages in Gmail. (I am not sending the message or replying to an existing message, these are just being created with labels and left there). I have a thread Id for my messages that I need to use to group them together in Gmail, but I can't seem to get it working - messages are shown in Gmail as separate, not in a thread. My first thought was to use the "threadId" property in the json of the insert, but this causes http error 404 ""Requested entity was not found."

In my RFC message headers, I am creating the relevant threading headers as follows:

```
Subject: Performance issue with libcurl 7.73
MIME-Version: 1.0
Message-ID: <17576c8ef0591c6e>
In-Reply-To: <17576c8ef0591c6e>
References: <17576c8ef0591c6e>
```

So I create 2 messages with the above headers, all values identical except that the 2nd subject begins with "Re:".  Does not work to thread them together. Any ideas?

Comment: The subjects must also match. Did you try that?

Comment: That would be an unacceptable solution, since subject prefixes such as "Re:" should be ignored when grouping messages into threads (as Gmail itself does with native messages).  In any case, yes I did try making the subjects identical, and it makes no difference.

Comment: Can you provide the [minimal code necessary to reproduce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) your issue?